# 'MemoizedSelector<StateInterface, boolean>' is not assignable to parameter of type '"isAuthentificated"'

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

i started using ngrx/store at one of the projects and so far got great results.

Whole app is working well and is compiled successfully, but typescript compiler throws an error into command line when doing ng serve

> ERROR in src/app/auth.service.ts(28,48): error TS2345: Argument of
>   type 'MemoizedSelector' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '"isAuthentificated"'.

Corresponding code:

```
this.isAuthentificated = `this.store.select(selectAuthentificationStateSelector);`
```

isAuthentificated is defined like this:

```
Observable<AuthStateInterface>
```

and the selector looks like this:

```
export const selectAuthentificationState = (state: StateInterface) => {
  return state.auth;
};
export const selectAuthentificationStateSelector = createSelector(
  selectAuthentificationState,
  (state: AuthStateInterface) => {
    return state.isAuthentificated;
  }
};
```

Any idea why the error occurs? App is working as supposed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Argument of type 'MemoizedSelector<ICommonAppState, IMenuItemsObject\[\]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51016558/argument-of-type-memoizedselectoricommonappstate-imenuitemsobject-is-not)